# Passing data between Controller Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi I cant find the way to pass data between Action methods within one controller. The simplified code example is as follows:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    int latestID;

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        latestID = 50000;
        return View();
    }

    // GET: Generate
    public ActionResult Generate()
    {
        // using the latestID here 
        return View();
    }
}
```

Index loads when the app starts and `latestID` is set to 50000. But when I click button mapped to API GET request Generate, the `latestID` is suddenly null. I tried to implement TempData and Session but with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov never ever use a `static` that store user's data in a web aplication.

Comment: @CodeNotFound there is no line in this question that he is storing user's data in that latestID

Comment: What is the real purpose of `latestId`? Does it contain user's data? More details may help you get a best practice.

Comment: @CodeNotFound latestID represents the latest ID of movie in database.

Comment: Ok. But why you need to store it in your Web Application? I mean when you get the ID how do you use it? If we have the answer, I may help you with a good practice because storing database Id like you want to do is a bad practice.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov the database is not mine. The ID is get by GET request from API.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov your action should receive this argument as a property. instead to get something global.

Comment: @NicolasTakashi my action? :)

Comment: @CodeNotFound I use it to generate random ID up to the latest ID.

Comment: @mosses If you want user to get the ramdom data you can do it directly in the database. Which database are you using?

Comment: @mosses you could use it as a parameter. when the user navigates to yoursite/home/generate?id=5000 you can catch it in your action method
public ActionResult Generate(int? id)

Comment: @CodeNotFound I use The Movie DB API. The latest ID changes every few minutes so I need to GET that everytime the app loads.

Comment: @EgeTuncoz I thought about this but I dont want to show the ID in the URL.

Comment: @mosses what I trying to explain you is that in database IDs are not continuous you can have something like this: 1, 2, 3, 10. What happened if you randomly use 4, 5, 6, 7 or 8. Those IDs don't exist in your database. That is what you need to ramdonly choose the Id with a query inside the databse. Show us your logic it may help a lot.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I know what you mean. I have taken care of that. The thing is ID always exists, it just returns JSON with error code which I check and if that happens I make new generation. That is basically the whole logic I have right now.

Comment: The web is stateless. Each time you make a request, a new instance of your controller is initialized (and `latestID` gets initialized to its default value). Setting a value for it in the  `Index` method is pointless because as soon and the method finishes, it disposed

Comment: @StephenMuecke  +1 for the point made

Comment: Anyway if you still want to use a bad practice and store the latest id you can choose to store it into => `this.HttpContext.Application.Add("LatestId", "your_value_here"); ` And if you want to retrieve it use `var latestId = int.Parse(this.HttpContext.Application["LatestId"].ToString();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke that really helps me understand why the variable is always set to null. Thank you. I would still be grateful for someone to show me good practice to achieve what I need.

Comment: You need to persist the value somewhere (e.g. a database, a file, `Session` .... )

Comment: @mosses A good practice would be to have auto-incrementing `ID`s in your database table(s). If needed, do a web search for `[Name of your RDBMS] auto increment primary key` and follow the examples. You will then be freed from this burden.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there are 2 possibilities here i.e. the value to be retrieved is for a user session or its global across all the users using the website.

If the value is user specific then it can be managed through session stage management like Viewbag. Or if this value is expected to be maintained on the server side alone then it needs to be retrieved again through some persistence mechanism like database or memory cache.

If the value is common across all the users using the Website then it can be achieved through the Dependency Injection of a singleton object (this can be a database manager or cache manager again or a simple in memory object). The static objects can be used as well but it wouldn't be ideal as the application wouldn't support horizontal scalability across instances.